# Bootstrap popover removes margin on Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, popover

On http://twitchplayspokemon.org/ - the circles above the images. When you hover over them, a popover appears, with text in it. Now, this works perfectly on Firefox and IE, but on Chrome, it removes the space between the circles when there's two of them. I can't for the life of me find out what this is. Anyone have a clue?

Edit: Fixed by removing the line breaks, and rather adding margin-left than rely on spaces.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  If so, what did you do to solve the issue?